# Seat Leon TDI Stylance 2007

Tags: manual-transmission, seat-cars, seat-leon

i have a seat Leon tdi stylance 2007 it's covered 11800 miles, my gearbox if you go from 2nd to 3rd gear at slow speed the gear will crunch, the car has covered 118000 on the clock, any ideas guys cheers.

Comment: Are you sure you're depressing the clutch pedal all the way when you shift gears?

Answer (score 1):

If you are operating the clutch correctly, then I would suspect the 3rd gear synchro - may need to get it checked by a good mechanic.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is bleed the clutch and replace the gearbox oil.  I would also reset the gear linkage, [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sheTKD03hmo) Youtube video explains the procedure to reset the gear linkage.  After these three servicing steps, you may find that the problem goes away.